# Google Pub/Sub Big Query subscription schema mistmach

Tags: google-bigquery, gcloud, google-cloud-pubsub

I've successfully created BigQuery subscription for Pub/Sub topic.

Subscription schema options used:

- Use table schema
- Write metadata
- Drop unknown fields

Topic does not have a schema. I assumed that is not required but I might be wrong.

Now I'm publishing messages to the topic however subscription shows an error saying "The subscription cannot receive messages because of resource errors."

Subscription state is: `table schema mismatch`.

I'm not able to find anything in the logs about specific mismatch.

```json
[
    {
        "name": "subscription_name",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "REQUIRED",
        "description": "Pub/Sub subscription name"
    },
    {
        "name": "message_id",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "REQUIRED",
        "description": "Pub/Sub message identifier"
    },
    {
        "name": "publish_time",
        "type": "TIMESTAMP",
        "mode": "REQUIRED",
        "description": "Pub/Sub publishing time"
    },
    {
        "name": "attributes",
        "type": "JSON",
        "mode": "REQUIRED",
        "description": "Pub/Sub message attributes"
    },
    {
        "name": "id",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "REQUIRED",
        "description": "Message identifier"
    },
    {
        "name": "vendor_id",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "REQUIRED",
        "description": "Message vendor identifier"
    },
    {
        "name": "account",
        "type": "string",
        "mode": "REQUIRED",
        "description": "EmailEngine account identifier"
    },
    {
        "name": "path",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "REQUIRED",
        "description": "Mailbox path"
    },
    {
        "name": "created_on",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "REQUIRED",
        "description": "Creation date"
    },
    {
        "name": "from",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "REQUIRED",
        "description": "Message sender"
    },
    {
        "name": "subject",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "NULLABLE",
        "description": "Message subject"
    },
    {
        "name": "body",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "NULLABLE",
        "description": "Message body"
    },
    {
        "name": "body_type",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "NULLABLE",
        "description": "Message body type (plain, html or markdown)"
    },
    {
        "name": "to",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
    },
    {
        "name": "cc",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
    },
    {
        "name": "bcc",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
    },
    {
        "name": "reply_to",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
    },
    {
        "name": "in_reply_to",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
    },
    {
        "name": "is_auto_reply",
        "type": "BOOLEAN",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
    },
    {
        "name": "labels",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
    },
    {
        "name": "flags",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
    },
    {
        "name": "sender_role",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "NULLABLE",
        "description": "Classified sender role"
    },
    {
        "name": "message_category",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "NULLABLE",
        "description": "Classified message category"
    },
    {
        "name": "duration",
        "type": "INTEGER",
        "mode": "NULLABLE",
        "description": "Classification duration"
    },
    {
        "name": "prompt_tokens",
        "type": "INTEGER",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
    },
    {
        "name": "completion_tokens",
        "type": "INTEGER",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
    },
    {
        "name": "total_tokens",
        "type": "INTEGER",
        "mode": "NULLABLE",
        "description": "Total tokens used for the interaction with LLM"
    },
    {
        "name": "payload",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "NULLABLE",
        "description": "Classification payload from LLM"
    }
]
```

PubSub message:

```json
{
  "id": "<id.com>",
  "vendor_id": "AAAAAQAAAyY",
  "account": "naxj4rkbqadgqppi",
  "path": "INBOX",
  "created_on": "2024-02-08T15:15:53+00:00",
  "from": "John Doe <john.doe@gmail.com>",
  "subject": "Subject",
  "body": "Message body",
  "body_type": "md",
  "to": "Mark Doe <mark.doe@gmail.com>",
  "cc": null,
  "bcc": null,
  "reply_to": null,
  "in_reply_to": null,
  "is_auto_reply": false,
  "labels": "",
  "flags": "",
  "sender_role": "internal",
  "message_category": null,
  "duration": 12,
  "prompt_tokens": 1637,
  "completion_tokens": 7,
  "total_tokens": 1644,
  "payload": "{"json": "payload"}"
}
```

Question is what is wrong with the schema or how to find error details?

Answer (score 1):

There is currently an [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/324412361) with `use_table_schema` such that even a single bad message could put the subscription into the "schema mismatch" state permanently. This is not intended behavior and a fix is to be rolled out by 2/16/2024.

Comment: That was the problem indeed. I've updated the schema but "schema mistmatch" prevented subscription for working properly. Is there any way to see more detailed information about the error message? Schema mismatch error is not visible in the logs.